# Strange spacing between <body> and div with display:box

Tags: css, flexbox

This is very weird, there's nothing like margin or padding, but I still having a space between  and first div that is 100% height and width, with display:box property.

Testing on Firefox 20

```
</head> 
<body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="blueDiv">
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ByWwz/

Comment: Please don't use properties from the 2009 Flexbox spec (`display: box`) without also including properties from the modern spec (`display: flex`).  Those old properties won't be here forever!  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: @cimmanon thanks I was just following a tut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add `vertical-align: top` to `#outer`, the space disappears

http://jsfiddle.net/9BvTg/1

Comment: Firefox versions that implement the spec using `display: box` are quite buggy and do all sorts of unexpected things.  Firefox treats *flex containers* as something more like an inline-table than a block, so it does not surprise me that something like this would work.

Comment: No I just supposed that an object with that kind of display property (that I never used) may have a default baseline vertical alignment as for inline blocks element o inline replaced elements (like images)

Comment: @cimmanon I have tried to use display: flexbox and doesn't seem to be supported, and I think firefox doesn't have the new syntax in the current version. Anyway, seems a little fast to adopt flexbox, maybe I will use just positioned divs.

Comment: Firefox *won't* be supporting `display: flexbox` because that's also from an outdated spec.  It and Safari are the only "major" browsers that currently only support `display: box`.  Everyone else (with the exception of IE10) is moving towards `display: flex` (Chrome and Opera already support it).